# DRYing repeated rescue statements

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I use stripe as a payment processor.

Within the application, I send a request to Stripe to execute charge or for other types of processes, and basically use the same error handling boilerplate like below.

```
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e,  
  # do something
rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e, 
  # do something
rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e, 
  # do something
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  # do something
rescue => e
  # do something
end
```

While I could definitely `rescue` each of these error types in each API call, that's a lot of boilerplate code, I'd love to just `rescue` on all of them, and then build a method to do things such as logging, sending notification.

How can I bundle these into one exception handler in a cleaner way (dry things up) like below?

```
def call
   plan = Plan.new(attrs)
   return plan unless plan.valid?

   begin
     external_card_plan_service.create(api_attrs)
   rescue Exceptions::Stripe => e
     plan.errors[:base] << e.message
     return plan
   end

   plan.save
   plan.update(is_active: true, activated_at: Time.now.utc)
   plan
 end
```

Comment: If Stripe is yours, you can have these exceptions inherit a common exception. Is it?

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure if `do something` is same for each case or not. If not, this might do what you want:

```
def handle_stripe_errors
  yield
rescue Stripe::AuthenticationError => e, 
  # do something
rescue Stripe::APIConnectionError => e, 
  # do something
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  # do something
rescue => e
  # do something
end

handle_stripe_errors do
  external_card_plan_service.create(api_attrs)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this seems to me very clear. I just wonder if # do something are the exact same, should I create some modules for 'handle_stripe_errors' and where should I put the module?

Comment: If `# do something` are same, you can probably use maxple's solution. I don't know the architecture of your program, so can't tell you where would be the best place for the wrapper function.

Comment: I use those within service object and webhook to expand metadata.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhere in your app define a variable/constant/method which returns a list of the errors you want to rescue. For example:

```
STRIPE_ERRORS = [Stripe::InvalidRequestError, String::AuthenticationError]
```

The in your rescue block, you can use a splat operator to rescue any of these:

```
   begin
     <raise errors>
   rescue *STRIPE_ERRORS => e
     <handle errors>
   end
```

You can check which of the errors was raised with `e.class`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that combines with Max's and Amadan's solution that DRY's it up a little more and makes a reusable class.

This solution makes use of Rails `around_action` where you can define an action in a controller that surrounds its methods.

i.e

```
...
STRIPE_ERRORS = [Stripe::InvalidRequestError, String::AuthenticationError, ...]

around_action :stripe_error_handler
...

def stripe_error_handler
  yield
rescue *STRIPE_ERRORS => e
     <handle errors>
end
...
```

**You can specify which methods the `around_action` applies to!

To make it a little more reusable you can define a class that contains a constant STRIPE_ERRORS and initializes with e in the rescue section (`StripeErrorHander.new(e)`) that way you can specify the behaviours for each Stripe error (maybe send an email/slack message on a specific error, make the error message a little more human readable).

A simplified look at the class could look something like this:

```
class StripeErrorHandler
  STRIPE_ERRORS = [
    Stripe::CardError,
    Stripe::RateLimitError,
    ...
  ].freeze

  def initialize(error)
    @error = error
  end

  def message
    @error.message
  end

  def status
    case @error
    when Stripe::CardError
      :unprocessable_entity
    when Stripe::RateLimitError
      :service_unavailable
    else
      :internal_server_error
    end
  end
end
```